# can php variables be defined inside a javascript code

Tags: php, javascript

The code:

```
if( 4 > 1 ) {
    alert('ok');
    <?php $mode = true;?>
} else {
    alert('not-ok');
    <?php $mode = false;?>      
}
var_dump($mode);
```

This alerts OK, but the `var_damp()` shows `bool(false)`

Why is var_dump showing that $mode is false?

Comment: PHP is executed on the server, JavaScript in the browser

Comment: I don't think you understand how PHP is executed.

Answer (score 3):

You're confusing server-side code with client-side code.  The PHP doesn't continue to be interpreted in the browser.  By the time anything gets to the browser (which interprets the JavaScript code), the PHP is processed and done.

So essentially what you're doing in PHP is this:

```
$mode = true;
$mode = false;
var_dump($mode);
```

Which, naturally, will show `false`.  Then, after that's done executing, you're rendering this to the browser:

```
if(4>1){
    alert('ok');
} else {
    alert('not-ok');
}
```

Which, naturally, will `alert('ok')`.

You can essentially think of the server-side code and the client-side code as two entirely different application contexts.  Indeed, they kind of are.  The server-side application is just returning a page, it doesn't care what's on the page or what happens to the page.  The client-side application is what gets rendered to the browser and any code therein (JavaScript, in this case).  It doesn't care how it was generated by the server or even what server-side language was used (PHP, ASP, Java, etc.), it just does its thing in the browser.

Answer (score 1):

PHP code is executed on server before page is sent to the browser.  At this point, both code chunks: `$mode = true;` and `$mode = false;` will be executed, and final value of `$mode` will be false, so `var_dump($mode)` will print `bool|(false)`.  The page sent to browser will contain the following code:

```
if(4>1){

        alert('ok');


    } else {
        alert('not-ok');

    }
```

Your PHP chunks didn't print anything, so they will just turn to nothing.  Browser will execute this code and show window with `ok` in it.

Answer (score 0):

PHP - Server side - browser does not get a look in nor does Javascript.

So the code given would be delivered to the browser after the PHP has been processed.

Answer (score 0):

Because you cant assign any new php variables after php is done rendering the page. If you do want to do something like this you would probably have to use AJAX.

Answer (score 0):

you will get result using this code..

`<?php`

`echo "<script type='text/javascript'>";`

```
if(4>1){

    echo "alert('ok')";
    $mode = true;
```

`}`

```
else {
    echo "alert('ok')";
    $mode = false; 
}
```

`echo "</script>";`

`var_dump ($mode);`

`?>`

you can write javascript inside the php script..